# traversal of binary tree using one single queue

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-tree, breadth-first-search, tree-traversal

The code below is one way to traverse the binary tree using one queue

```
public List<List<Integer>> levelOrder(TreeNode root){
    List result = new ArrayList();
    
    if(root == null){
        return result; 
    }    
    Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    queue.offer(root);
    
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        ArrayList<Integer> level = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        int size = queue.size();
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            TreeNode head = queue.poll();
            level.add(head.val);            
            if(head.left != null){
                queue.offer(head.left);
            }
            if(head.right != null){
                queue.offer(head.right);
            }
        }
        result.add(level);
    }
    return result; 
}
```

I understand the logic but I wonder why do we need a temporary ArrayList, since we can just add the head.val to the result list? It should be the same? Could anyone explain why we still add:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> level = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder why do we need a temporary ArrayList, since we can just add the head.val to the result list? It should be the same?

You could, but the result would be different.

With the current code, the returned array is a nested array, where node values are grouped per level in their own subarray. Note that `result.add(level)` adds *one* entry in the `result` array, which itself is an array.

If you would add the node's value directly to the result list, the returned array would be a flat array.